How to check if an interceptor is provided in withInterceptors fucntion
In my library, There is an interceptor that the user must provide in order for the component to work.
I want to throw an exception if the user forgets to provide the interceptor, maybe from a singleton service.
How can I achieve that?
export function progressInterceptor(req: HttpRequest<unknown>, next: HttpHandlerFn): Observable<HttpEvent<unknown>> {

  return next(req).pipe(
    finalize(() => {
      // some code
    })
  );
}

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class NgProgressHttpManager {

  constructor() {
    // Some how I need to access the list of provided interceptors!
    if (!interceptor instanceof NgProgressInterceptor) {
      throw new Error('NgProgressInterceptor is not provided. Please add it to the HTTP client interceptors.');
    }
  }
}

bootstrapApplication(AppComponent, {
  providers: [
    provideHttpClient(
      withInterceptors([
       // in case user forgot to add 'progressInterceptor'
      ])
    )
  ]
}).catch(err => console.error(err));


Use Angular's InjectionToken to create a unique token for the interceptor.  inject the interceptor using the token you created in your NgProgressHttpManager. interceptor is not provided, throw an error.

@Hercule That does not guarantee the injector is added to withInterceptors

Create a service that holds a property which is not used anywhere first.
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class SomeService {
    interceptorPresent = false;
}

Then on the interceptor toggle this flag to true.
export function progressInterceptor(req: HttpRequest<unknown>, next: HttpHandlerFn): Observable<HttpEvent<unknown>> {
  const someService = inject(SomeService);
  if(someService) { 
    someService.interceptorPresent = true; 
  }
  return next(req).pipe(
    finalize(() => {
      // some code
    })
  );
}

Finally in the component use this flag to throw the desired error.
export class SomeComponentOrServiceDoesntMatter {
     constructor(private someService: SomeService) {
        if (!someService?.interceptorPresent) {
          throw new Error('NgProgressInterceptor is not provided. Please add it to the HTTP client interceptors.');
        }
     }
}


In this case the interceptor has to be called at least once. but maybe the component might be initialized before any request has happened!

@MurhafSousli If you apply this approach to traditional interceptor using class instead of function, then you can set the flag in the constructor, just make sure you do not have providedIn: 'root' on the @Injectable decorator

@MurhafSousli one more thing to do, is to place the if condition in one of the subscribe of the component, so it will guarantee the API call and interceptor have ran
